# How to define MaterialShapeDrawable in XML - Android

Tags: android, xml, vector, material-design, android-drawable

I wanna use the beautiful MaterialShapeDrawable within an XML file in /res/drawable of my Android project, but whenever I try to define it like Views in /layout/ XMLs I see:

```
Element com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable is not allowed here
```

While trying:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?attr/colorPrimary">
    <item>
        <com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable />
    </item>
</ripple>`
```

Isn't there any method to ease this job using XMLs? What kind of namespaces do I have to add?

Comment: `MaterialShapeDrawable` is a library class, so the platform `DrawableInflater` isn't aware of it, and there is no XML tag for it. At API level 24, you can use any class with the `<drawable class="…" />` construct, but `MaterialShapeDrawable` wasn't designed to be inflated, so you'd have to subclass it to implement `inflate()`. You'd also have to process all of the attributes yourself, and you don't have access to a `Context` object there, so you'd have to handle the shape appearance ones manually, too. FWIW, all of the library components that use `MaterialShapeDrawable` just create it in code.